# I want to animate some text from left to right using CSS for WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I want to animate a text coming from left to right, the text says "Free Shipping on order over €49". How can I write the code for this text? I want to place it in the middle.

[image: screenshot of my website]

Here is the code I have tried, but I don't want this reverse animation and speed have to be more faster.

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  animation: linear infinite alternate;
  animation-name: run;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes run {
    0% {
      left: 0;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      left: 100%;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
<img id="pot" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

```html
<img id="pot" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width="100px" height="100px"
```

Comment: Please share your code so far and what you've tried, Stack Overflow isn't a place where people will just do work for you. You have to show that you've put in an effort first.

Comment: already added please answer now

Comment: If you want this to be faster, I presume you just reduce the `animation-duration`?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are using `infinite` which will loop your animation forever. So remove that. To speed up the animation you can lower the value of `animation-duration`. And to make sure that the position of your element will not reset at the end of the animation use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. You can also set `animation-timing-function` to make the whole thing more smooth.

You can combine all of these into one line of CSS: `animation: ease 0.3s forwards;`

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  animation: ease 0.3s forwards;
  animation-name: run;
}

@-webkit-keyframes run {
    0% {
      left: 0;
    }
    100% {
      left: 100%;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="pot" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.